# Generate string that doesn't match one in set

Tags: c++, string, stl

Sort of an odd question- how would I go about generating a character string that doesn't match any in a set of strings? I don't want to make any assumptions about the strings. Solution is ideally STL based, but doesn't have to be

Example:

```
vector<string> strings;
/*...*/
string unMatching = generateUnmatching(strings); //this is the function I want

assert(find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), unMatching) == strings.end());
```

Comment: Why does this sound suspiciously like homework?

Comment: I promise it wasn't, but for the life of me I can't remember why I asked this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use [diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument):

- Start with an empty string s.
- Look at the first character of the first string in the set. Choose any character other than that one, and append it to s.
- Look at the second character of the second string in the set. Choose any character other than that one, and append it to s.
- Follow the same pattern, always looking at the ith character of the ith string and appending a different character to s.
- When you've finished with the last string in the set, s will differ from every string in the set in at least one position.

Another method would be to copy the longest string in the set and append any character to the copy. This new string will be different from every string in the set.

There are all kinds of other ways to accomplish the same thing. Adding some constraints to the problem would help in selecting an algorithm that makes the most sense for your problem. For example, you might decide to generate the shortest string that doesn't match any string in the set, or one with the lowest lexigraphic sort value, or one with the smallest number of characters in common with the other strings, or...

Comment: Doesn't this assume that all the strings in the set are of a particular length? (e.g. what if the 6th string is of length 2?)

Comment: @JamesBedford Not really. If the length of the ith string is less than i, you're free to choose any character at all. If the 6th string has length 2, then putting any character in the 6th position of s makes s different from that string.

Comment: No, any character is different from missing(after end of string) character, so simply use any ("a").

Answer (score 2):

You could use a uuid generator, like the one from boost:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>    

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::uuids;
    random_generator gen;
    uuid u = gen();
    std::string s = to_string(u);
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't have any requirement about the result string, you could simply do:

```
string answer = "a";
while (find(strings.begin(), strings.end(), unMatching) != strings.end())
    answer += "a";
```

Apparently it doesn't seem to be what you want.

Here's the optimized solution that helps you find the shortest possible answer in the least amount of time:

1. Build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with your character set.
2. Do a breadth-first search from the root node, the first encountered empty node would be the shortest answer.

The time complexity of the optimized implementation is O(number_of_characters_in_all_strings), while a simple implementation with vector loop and lookup would be O(number_of_strings*lenth_of_string).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a random number generator (an example below) I think the ascii printable characters start at 33 and end at 127 and from -1 to -95

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> //only for printf
#define RANDINT(r) ((int)(r * (float)random() /(float)RAND_MAX + 0.5))
#define OFFSETRANDINT(r,o) (RANDINT(r) + o)
#define RANDINTX2Y(x,y) (OFFSETRANDINT((y-x),x))

int main(){
  srandom(time(NULL)); // important to call this first, but only once
  printf("%d\n",RANDINT(2147483647)); //a random int between 0 and 2147483647
  printf("%d\n",OFFSETRANDINT(10,10)); //starting @ 10 with a range of 10 (10-20)
  printf("%d\n",RANDINTX2Y(0,10)); //between 0 and 10
}
```

you may need to cast the int to (char) so that you can store it in a string

then you can use either strstr or strcasestr depending on whether case matters
just strcat each string onto the "haystack" if it returns ! TRUE

```
#include <string.h>
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```